# Adding key value pairs to an array that have the same key

Tags: php, arrays

I need to create an array that has multiple key value pairs where the key is the same. Doing the following doesn't work because it simply updates the existing key with the new value instead of adding to the array.

```
$image_paths = array();

for($i=0; $i<10; $i++)
{
    $image_paths['string'] = $i;
}
```

The reason I need to do this is because I'm working with a soap server and one of the elements looks like this:

```
<ImagePaths>
  <string>string</string>
  <string>string</string>
</ImagePaths>
```

Is it even possible to create an array with multiple keys that are the same value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No thats not possible because the key is a unique identifier.

You will have to use a multidimensional array.

```
$image_paths['strings'][] = $i;
```

Comment: I figured as much. Thanks.